# Why can I not enable breakpoints in Visual Studio 2005?

Tags: debugging, visual-studio-2005, windows-ce, breakpoints, platform-builder

I have seen that sometimes breakpoints cannot be enabled in Visual Studio, they appear as empty circles, with a warning sign when enabled. This icon change is all the information VS gives.

Particularly I'm suffering that in a Windows CE 6.0 project where I cannot enable any breakpoint in any of the sub-projects or in the OS design. The target platform in this project is a Vortex x86 embedded board, I use KITL for remote debugging.

How can I retrieve more information about what is happening?
Is it not possible to use breakpoints in my case?

Comment: Did you try to set the breakpoints and do rebuild BSP and Sub Projects?
I don't know how to explain this (probably has to do with mismatched pdb files), but this sometimes resolved me situations in which the breakpoints did not instantiate.

Comment: By the way, a more appropriate tag for this question would be Platform-Builder6 instead of kitl.

Comment: What, exactly, are you unable to debug?  KErnel?  Driver?  Application?

Comment: I'm trying to put breakpoints in an application

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The hollow circles with the yellow warning sign are OK. The breakpoint should instantiate once the module that holds that breakpoint loads.
This of course happens in a debug image only.

Comment: Did you try to put a breakpoint using DebugBreak() explicitly?

Comment: Ok, as you said, the hollow circles were ok, I finally have the breakpoints working enabling the kernel debugger (IMGNODEBUGGER=1) and running the application from the Target->Run Programs... dialog.

Answer (score 0):

Are you running/compiling a debuggable version of your projects - I seem to remeber if there were no symbols loaded then this was the casE?

Comment: Yes, I'm compiling for debug. .pdb files are also created. Should I check something else?